# How do I get the full path of an "Open With" application in Windows?

Tags: c#

I know I can get the default "Open With" application name, for a file extension, by using

```
String ext = ".dds"
String baseKey="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\";
Object mruObj = Registry.GetValue(baseKey + ext + "\\OpenWithList", "MRUList", null);

if(mruObj != null)
{
    String key = ((String)mruObj).Substring(0, 1);
    Object progObj = Registry.GetValue(baseKey + ext + "\\OpenWithList", key, null);
    if(progObj != null)
    {
        //(String)progObj = "Photoshop.exe"
    }
}
```

I also know that I can get the full path by starting a new process, with a file with said extension, and reading the return `Process` object's `Module[0].Filename`

So, if Windows can come up with the path of the associated application, without it being stored in PATH, in order to start it in the first place, then there has to be a way to get that same info without starting a process. I'm hoping that someone can share that "way" with me.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/649104/How-to-get-EXE-associated-with-a-File-Extension-in) might be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately not. CLASSES_ROOT is a good source, but Explorer/FileExts will cover any existing associations that the former doesn't have. Since it's up to the application/installer to register the extension in CLASSES_ROOT, there are a lot of extensions that are associated on the user end, via "Open With"

Comment: Glad I used 'might' i/o 'will'.

Comment: Actually... I replied a bit hastily. I made the mistake of only looking at the first part, where it uses the extension keys, and missed the second part, where it looks up the app name in CLASSES_ROOT/Applications, for the shell/open/command. My apologies.